# Extjs accessing father from child belongsTo relationship

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need a little help, I've been struggling with this for days! : I'm trying to access the father from a child in a belongsTo relationship, I've tried everything, every example, and nothing! :( what am I doing wrong, here is my code:

**Father:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Career', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,idProperty: 'CareerID'
    ,fields: ['Name', 'SchoolID',
        {
            name : 'CareerID',
            type: 'int'

        }
    ]
    ,proxy: {
        type: 'ajax'        
        ,url: 'fakeServices/careers.js'        
        ,reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

**Child:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Course', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,fields: ['CourseID', 'Name', 'CourseStatusID', 'Description',
        {
            name: 'CareerFK',
            type: 'int'
        }]
    ,belongsTo: {            
        model:'Career',
        primaryKey: 'CareerID',
        foreignKey: 'CareerFK',
        associationKey: 'Career'
    },proxy: {
        type: 'ajax'
        ,url: 'fakeServices/courses.js'
        ,reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }

});
```

**How I'm loading (Courses is a simple Store with no proxy, just declaring the Course Model):**

```
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Courses').load();
```

**Json:**

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "data" : [{
        "CourseID": 1,
            "Name": "Curso1",
            "CourseStatusID": "1",
            "Description": "Learn!",
            "CareerFK" : 1,
            "Career": {
            "CareerID" : 1,
                "Name": "Engineering"
            }
    }]
}
```

**What I'm specting (getCareer method should exist, but it doesn't, all the fields in the Course Model have the JSON data loaded correctly):**

```
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Courses').load();
Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Courses').data.items[0].getCareer();
```

PS: I've tried to replacing belogsTo for associations:[{type: 'belongsTo'}], it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for your Help @AndreiI , when I do get("career") it returns undefined. It's because "career" is not declared as a field in the model, I don't want it as a field, I want it as a realationship